# Tools for gathering metrics about physical environment for use in virtualization/cloud planning?

Tags: virtualization, cloud, metrics, iops, utilization

I'm looking for tools that will work on either Linux/Unix or Windows Server that for a given set of servers in an enterprise environent, will:

- Identify the server [via hostname, or some other unique attribute]
- List the the number & type of CPUs + cores
- Enumerate the storage devices used by the server
- Provide CPU and storage utilization data
- Provide load, network & storage I/O metrics

The goal is to gather accurate metrics about the current environment that will drive the design of an equivelent environment virtually or in the IaaS cloud [e.g AWS].

I found a couple of options so far:

- [SysTrack Virtual Machine Planner](http://www.lakesidesoftware.com/systrack_vmp.aspx)
- [Microsoft Assessment and Planning Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb977556.aspx)

Some of this data can be gathered directly from the OS but I rather use a tool that has that functionality and presents the data in an easy to understand manner. Does VMWare provide any tools for this?  Other suggestions?

Comment: I am looking for a similar set of tools. Execs want numbers and right now the calculator tools provided by places like Amazon and Azure ask you to assume a lot.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare used to offer a product called "Guided Consolidation" that did just what you describe but it appears to no longer by available and possibly replaced with a product I've not personally used called "IT Advisor" that's part of the "[VMWare Go](http://www.vmware.com/products/go/features.html)" product set.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Exoprise.com](https://www.exoprise.com), which collects thousands of underlying resource metrics and provide a complete endpoint picture for measuring digital experience.